# How can I split these lines with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a page and I need to split the words on it to an array.

My file is like this

```
dssds
* Eski çağlarsda bazıhastaslıklara isyi geldisğine insan büyüslü söz
dsds
* Abramsak işi, idare.
dsdsds
* Abramsak işi, idare.
dsdsds
* Abramdak işi, idare.
```

I need to put all the word which don't have a * in their line and which have one word in the same line in an array. If that can be 
how can I do this with a regular expression?

My output  array must be like

```
[abrakadabra, abrsamaas ,abradsma ,aswabrama ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use

```
^[^*]\S*
```

this and do a `match` instead of `split`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iV6mP5/2

```
$re = "/^[^*]\\S*/m"; 
$str = "abrakadabra\n* Eski çağlarda bazıhastalıklara iyi geldiğine inanılan büyülü söz\nabramaas\n* Abramak işi, idare.\nabradsma\n* Abramak işi, idare.\naswabrama\n* Abramak işi, idare."; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: thank you so much yes its work but there is problem now 
my file has 176000  line (8 miga ) and  preg_match_all it's not working with this big file .

your code is working with what i wrote  above but i get problem when i use it with this big of files

Comment: @user44444 you can split the file or read `1000` lines in one or something like that.